# Auto Lisp to replace (underscore+Number) in a Layer name but ignore any single underscores between letters

Tags: lisp, rename, layer, autocad, autolisp

I am trying to rename a large amount of layers that contain `_1` and `_2` in the Layer name for example:

`AAA_XXX_1_CP` or `AAA_XXX_2_DD`

I want to remove the `_1` and `_2` but leave all the other underscores in the new layer name so the new names would be:

`AAA_XXX_CP` or `AAA_XXX_DD`

I have a Lisp routine I am trying to adapt but it is taking all of the underscores out leaving this

`AAAXXXCP` or `AAAXXXDD`

Here is the Lisp I am trying to adapt.

```
(vl-load-com)
(defun C:SLPC (/ layname fixed); = Strip Layer names of numbers _1 & _2
  (vlax-for layer (vla-get-layers (vla-get-activedocument (vlax-get-acad-object))) 
    (setq
      layname (vla-get-name layer)
      fixed (vl-string-translate "_1_2" "   " layname)
        ; replace all such characters with spaces
    ); setq
    (while (wcmatch fixed "* *") (setq fixed (vl-string-subst "" " " fixed)))
      ; remove all spaces [original as well as just-substituted]
    (if
      (and
        (not (tblsearch "layer" fixed)); doesn't duplicate an existing Layer name
        (/= fixed ""); wasn't made of only such characters [reduced to nothing]
      ); and
      (vla-put-name layer fixed); rename it
    ); if
  ); vlax-for
  (princ)
); defun
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at the help entry for "vl-string-translate". It is interpreting each character of your sourceset as a replacement character. It is not seeing "_1" and "_2" but "_", "1", and "2" as items to be replaced in your string. That is why it is taking out all of your underscores. You can probably skip the translate and just use "vl-string-subst" to get the job done.

Replace

```
    (setq layname (vla-get-name layer) fixed (vl-string-translate "_1_2" " " layname);
    setq (while (wcmatch fixed "**") 
    (setq fixed (vl-string-subst "" " " fixed)))
```

With

```
    (setq layname (vla-get-name layer) fixed (vl-string-subst "_1" "" layname);
    (setq layname (vla-get-name layer) fixed (vl-string-subst "_2" "" layname);
    setq (while (wcmatch fixed "**")
```

Comment: This helped I swapped the "translate" for "subst" but also swapped the _1 position to this (vl-string-subst " " "_1" layname)

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked for my needs - it could maybe be made more efficient though.

```
(vl-load-com)
(defun C:SLPC (/ layname layname2 fixed fixed2); = Strip Layer names of numbers _1 & _2
  (vlax-for layer (vla-get-layers (vla-get-activedocument (vlax-get-acad-object)))
  (setq
    layname (vla-get-name layer)
    fixed (vl-string-subst " " "_1" layname)
     ; replace all such characters with spaces
    ); setq
    (while (wcmatch fixed "* *") (setq fixed (vl-string-subst "" " " fixed)))
    ; remove all spaces [original as well as just-substituted]
    (if
      (and
        (not (tblsearch "layer" fixed)); doesn't duplicate an existing Layer name
        (/= fixed ""); wasn't made of only such characters [reduced to nothing]
      ); and
      (vla-put-name layer fixed); rename it
      ); if
    ); vlax-for
   (princ)
;
; now the no2
;
(vlax-for layer (vla-get-layers (vla-get-activedocument (vlax-get-acad-object)))
  (setq
    layname2 (vla-get-name layer)
    fixed2 (vl-string-subst " " "_2" layname2)
    ; replace all such characters with spaces
    ); setq
    (while (wcmatch fixed2 "* *") (setq fixed2 (vl-string-subst "" " " fixed2)))
    ; remove all spaces [original as well as just-substituted]
    (if
      (and
        (not (tblsearch "layer" fixed2)); doesn't duplicate an existing Layer name
        (/= fixed2 ""); wasn't made of only such characters [reduced to nothing]
      ); and
      (vla-put-name layer fixed2); rename it
      ); if
    ); vlax-for
   (princ)
); defun
```

Comment: Can format the code?

Comment: Need format the code